# Add Lightning Builder App to standard Lightning Nav Menu

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, lightning

Is there a way to add my Lightning Builder App to a standard Lightning Navigation Menu (not Salesforce1 Navigation)? Im able to add a Lightning Component to the menu, but Im having trouble finding a way to add an app (containing multiple components) to the menu. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe you can add an app to the menu.  Only a component.  Often end up having a top level component that is a wrapper around my functionality.  The app then only contains this component.  Will expose this component through the UI and use the app for testing and development.